# In PyCharm, can I quickly view CSS properties applied via a class to an HTML element?

Tags: pycharm

While editing HTML in PyCharm, is there a way to quickly view the CSS properties that a CSS class applies to an HTML element? I've found that I can right click on an element and select "Show Applied Styles for Tag", but that only seems to show properties listed in the HTML's style attribute.

For example, if I have a CSS class in a stylesheet:

```
.my_css_class
{
   color: grey;
}
```

And an HTML element in a separate file:

```
<div class="my_css_class">Hello world</div>
```

How can I easily find out what "my_css_class" is doing to the `<div>` without navigating away from my HTML file?

I am using PyCharm Professional version 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one Tip of the Day that says this

> You can quickly review all styles currently applied to an HTML tag, by
>   right-clicking the tag name and selecting **Show Applied Styles For Tag**
>   from the context menu

:[image]

Comment: Hmm, this does seem to be what I'd normally consider correct. Unfortunately in my case, with all the Django {% extands '...' %} tags and various other import cases, it doesn't look like it works very well. I'll mark this answer correct anyway because I figure it would work for most projects?